Efficient selection of comparable rows from a table
I have a table of data recording information from two sensors:
Measurement (_sensorName_, _measureName_, _dateTime_, reading)

I query this data, in a view, inColumns, with a to obtain a wider table, like this:
SELECT 
    do, temp, t.dateTime, t.sensorName
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         reading AS do, dateTime, sensorName 
     FROM 
         measurement 
     WHERE 
         measureName = "DOppm") AS ppm,
    (SELECT 
         reading AS temp, dateTime, sensorName 
     FROM 
         measurement 
     WHERE 
         measureName = "Temperature") AS t
WHERE 
    ppm.dateTime = t.dateTime 
    AND ppm.sensorName = t.sensorName
ORDER BY 
    ppm.dateTime, ppm.sensorName;

Which produces a table of readings putting oxygen and temperature side-by-side:



do
temp
dateTime
sensorName




10
15
2024-08-20 16:59:00
sensor22


11
15
2024-08-20 16:56:00
sensor44



My problem is this: each sensor measures each the state of water (temperature, dissolved oxygen) every 12 minutes but the two are not in sync. So two compare the outcome of the two sensors I look for "similar" times - similar meaning, less than 6 minutes apart; which will always be the two closest readings from the two sensors.
I use much the same technique as above to obtain the closest reading:
SELECT 
    s22.doppm, s44.doppm, s22.temp, s44.temp, s22.dT
FROM
    (SELECT 
         doppm, temp, t.dateTime AS dT 
     FROM
         dataInColumns 
     WHERE 
         sensorName = "sensor22")  AS s22,
    (SELECT 
         doppm, temp, t.dateTime AS dT 
     FROM
         dataInColumns 
     WHERE
         sensorName = "sensor44") AS s44
WHERE
    ABS(DATEDIFF("n", s22.dT, s44.dT)) < 6
ORDER BY 
    s22.dateTime;

But the database computes the date difference for every pair of records so O(N^2) for N records. In the small data set (2000 readings of each) I have, this takes minutes to run the query. Yet as the times are indexed, and that it is known there is a recording from each sensor every 12 minutes, it should be possible to run this query in linear time O(N).
Is there a way to rewrite the query to run in linear time? I can do this in other languages than SQL, but as the data is in a relational database, I'd rather use an SQL query if it can be done efficiently.

Is this for MS Access for SQL Server; you've tagged both here. The use of double quotes (") for literal string identifiers suggests MS Access, as they are object delimit identifiers in T-SQL, which means your queries would fail in SQL Server.

Oops. I'm testing in access at present, though it will move to SQL-server in future. Access.

Perhaps you could "pivot" the data on 5 minute "buckets" or whatever, maybe it will not be perfect, but at least it will be fast :) Something like: select max(case sensorname when 'waterSensor' then reading end),max(case sensorname when 'tempSensor' then reading end)..., dateadd(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', readingTime) / 5 * 5, '19000101') from yourtable GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', readingTime) / 5 * 5

If you plan to move to SQL Server later, do the switch ASAP to avoid incompatibility issues.

You can join on the time condition instead of making a Cartesian product.
Also, there is no need for sub-selects. You can select FROM dataInColumns AS s22 and move the condition sensorName="sensor22" to the WHERE clause (and for s44 as well).
SELECT s22.doppm, s44.doppm, s22.temp, s44.temp, s22.dateTime as dT
FROM
    dataInColumns AS s22
    INNER JOIN dataInColumns AS s44
        ON Abs(DateDiff("n", s22.dateTime, s44.dateTime)) < 6
WHERE
    s22.sensorName="sensor22" AND
    s44.sensorName="sensor44"
ORDER BY s22.dateTime;

Keep in mind that you cannot infer the speed in SQL Server from the speed in Access. A query performing well (or badly) on one DB does not necessarily do so on the other one.
